# Update Vue subtraction method on input change

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I have a Vue method that subtracts expenses from income to derive disposable income.

Right now, the subtraction method fires on blur, but it should constantly fire while both the income or expenses value are updated. For example, while someone types their income into the income input, the disposable income span that models the subtraction method should update as each digit is typed. Similarly, if someone types any expense into one of the expense components, disposable income should update while the user is typing.

```js
    var budgetLine = Vue.extend({
        template: `
                <div>
                    <div class="row" v-for="item in items">
                        <input type="text" placeholder="Item"></input>
                        <input type="text" placeholder="How much?" v-model="item.qty"></input>
                        <button @click="addItem">+</button>
                        <button @click="removeItem">-</button>
                    </div>
                    <p id="result"><strong>Total:</strong> $ {{ totalQty }} </p>
                </div>
        `,

        data: function() {
        return {
            items: []
        };
        },
        watch: {
        totalQty(value) {
            this.$emit('update-expense', value)
        }
        },
        computed: {
        totalQty() {
            return this.items.reduce((total, item) => {
            return total + Number(item.qty);
            }, 0);
        },
        },

        methods: {
        addItem() {
            this.items.push({
            qty: 0
            });
        },
        removeItem(item) {
            this.items.pop(item);
        }
        },

        mounted() {
        this.addItem()
        }
    });

    var budgetApp = new Vue({
        el: '#app',
        data: {
        budgets: {
            'One': 0,
            'Two': 0,
            'Three': 0
        },
        form: {
            income: 0,
            expenses: 0,
            dispIncome: 0
        }
        },
        components: {
        'budget-line': budgetLine
        },
        watch: {
        budgets: {
            deep: true,
            handler() {
            this.form.expenses = this.budgetKeys.reduce((accum, key) => accum + this.budgets[key], 0)
            }
        }
        },
        computed: {
            budgetKeys() {
                return Object.keys(this.budgets)
            },
        },
        methods: {
            updateIncome(event) {
                this.form.income = event.target.value;
                this.form.dispIncome = this.form.income - this.form.expenses
            },
            updateExpenses(event) {
                this.form.expenses = event.target.value;
                this.form.dispIncome = this.form.income - this.form.expenses
            },
            calculateExpense(amount, budget) {
                this.budgets[budget] = amount;
            }
        }
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
        <header>
            <div class="header_container">  
                <div class="header_container-copy">  
                    <h1>Let's talk budget.</h1>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
                </div>
                <div class="header_container-results">  
                    <h2>Disposable Income</h2>
                    <div class="row"><span>Income:</span><span>{{ form.income }}</span></div>
                    <div class="row"><span>Expenses:</span><span>{{ form.expenses }}</span></div>
                    <div class="row"><span>Disposable Income:</span><span>{{ form.dispIncome }}</span></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </header>
        <h2>Income</h2>
        <input v-model="form.income" @change="updateIncome" type="number" class="form-control" name="income" id="income" placeholder="Income">
        <h2>Expenses</h2>
        <div class="budget" v-for="budget in budgetKeys">
            <h3>{{budget}}</h3>
            <budget-line v-on:update-expense="calculateExpense($event, budget)"></budget-line>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You're almost there, just need to watch for changes of this `form.income` model instead of updating the value by method.

### Working demo

```js
var budgetLine = Vue.extend({
    template: `
      <div>
        <div class="row" v-for="item in items">
          <input type="text" placeholder="Item"></input>
          <input type="text" placeholder="How much?" v-model="item.qty"></input>
          <button @click="addItem">+</button>
          <button @click="removeItem">-</button>
        </div>
        <p id="result"><strong>Total:</strong> $ {{ totalQty }} </p>
      </div>
    `, 

    data: function () {
      return {
        items: []
      };
    },
    watch: {
      totalQty(value) {
        this.$emit('update-expense', value)
      }
    },
    computed: {
      totalQty() {
        return this.items.reduce((total, item) => {
          return total + Number(item.qty);
        }, 0);
      },
    },

    methods: {
      addItem() {
        this.items.push({
          qty: 0
        });
      },
      removeItem(item) {
        this.items.pop(item);
      }
    },

    mounted() {
      this.addItem()
    }
  });

var budgetApp = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
      budgets: {
        'One': 0,
        'Two': 0,
        'Three': 0
      },
      form: {
        income: 0,
        expenses: 0,
        dispIncome: 0
      }
    },
    components: {
      'budget-line': budgetLine
    },
    watch: {
      budgets: {
        deep: true,
        handler(budget) {
          this.form.expenses = this.budgetKeys.reduce((accum, key) => accum + this.budgets[key], 0);
        }
      },
      
      'form.income'() {
        this.updateIncome();
      }
    },
    computed: {
      budgetKeys() {
        return Object.keys(this.budgets)
      },
    },
    methods: {
      updateIncome() {
        this.form.dispIncome = this.form.income - this.form.expenses;
      },
      calculateExpense(amount, budget) {
        this.budgets[budget] = this.form.expenses = amount;
        this.updateIncome();
      }
    }
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <header>
    <div class="header_container">
      <div class="header_container-copy">
        <h1>Let's talk budget.</h1>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
          dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="header_container-results">
        <h2>Disposable Income</h2>
        <div class="row"><span>Income:</span> <span>{{ form.income }}</span></div>
        <div class="row"><span>Expenses:</span> <span>{{ form.expenses }}</span></div>
        <div class="row"><span>Disposable Income:</span> <span>{{ form.dispIncome }}</span></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </header>
  <h2>Income</h2>
  <input v-model="form.income" type="number" class="form-control" name="income" id="income" placeholder="Income">
  <h2>Expenses</h2>
  <div class="budget" v-for="budget in budgetKeys">
    <h3>{{budget}}</h3>
    <budget-line v-on:update-expense="calculateExpense($event, budget)"></budget-line>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is close, but when I run the code snippet the expenses total at the top isn't summing up the One, Two and Three subtotals like it is in the original code.

Comment: @Nicole Answer updated. Turned out we got double watches by mistake. My bad, because I usually put my watch before the closing data object. Please re-run the above snippet and see if it works for you (try full-page view).

Comment: Thank you! Looks like there's still an issue now when I remove the last input from the individual budget lists. It gets added to the total instead of subtracted.

Comment: @Nicole That doesn't seem to be the case for me. Did you run the above snippet? I think your `computed` property (`totalQty`) does the accumulation job correctly. If you're implementing this, please be sure to update your `v-model` and the watches exactly like demonstrated above. Let me know if you still have issue then.

Answer (score 0):

first i think that  the  values ( Income, Expenses, Disposable Income) span will must be a computed property no a data , since they are values that are being calculated and rendered.
Anyway, as you already have it if you want a quick solution so that it works, you should implement :

> v-on:keyup="updateIncome"

into your input v-model="form.income" near  the @change function

```js
var budgetLine = Vue.extend({
        template: `
                <div>
                    <div class="row" v-for="item in items">
                        <input type="text" placeholder="Item"></input>
                        <input type="text" placeholder="How much?" v-model="item.qty"></input>
                        <button @click="addItem">+</button>
                        <button @click="removeItem">-</button>
                    </div>
                    <p id="result"><strong>Total:</strong> $ {{ totalQty }} </p>
                </div>
        `,

        data: function() {
        return {
            items: []
        };
        },
        watch: {
        totalQty(value) {
            this.$emit('update-expense', value)
        }
        },
        computed: {
        totalQty() {
            return this.items.reduce((total, item) => {
            return total + Number(item.qty);
            }, 0);
        },
        },

        methods: {
        addItem() {
            this.items.push({
            qty: 0
            });
        },
        removeItem(item) {
            this.items.pop(item);
        }
        },

        mounted() {
        this.addItem()
        }
    });

    var budgetApp = new Vue({
        el: '#app',
        data: {
        budgets: {
            'One': 0,
            'Two': 0,
            'Three': 0
        },
        form: {
            income: 0,
            expenses: 0,
            dispIncome: 0
        }
        },
        components: {
        'budget-line': budgetLine
        },
        watch: {
        budgets: {
            deep: true,
            handler() {
            this.form.expenses = this.budgetKeys.reduce((accum, key) => accum + this.budgets[key], 0)
            }
        }
        },
        computed: {
            budgetKeys() {
                return Object.keys(this.budgets)
            },
        },
        methods: {
            updateIncome(event) {
                this.form.income = event.target.value;
                this.form.dispIncome = this.form.income - this.form.expenses
            },
            updateExpenses(event) {
                this.form.expenses = event.target.value;
                this.form.dispIncome = this.form.income - this.form.expenses
            },
            calculateExpense(amount, budget) {
                this.budgets[budget] = amount;
            }
        }
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
        <header>
            <div class="header_container">  
                <div class="header_container-copy">  
                    <h1>Let's talk budget.</h1>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
                </div>
                <div class="header_container-results">  
                    <h2>Disposable Income</h2>
                    <div class="row"><span>Income:</span><span>{{ form.income }}</span></div>
                    <div class="row"><span>Expenses:</span><span>{{ form.expenses }}</span></div>
                    <div class="row"><span>Disposable Income:</span><span>{{ form.dispIncome }}</span></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </header>
        <h2>Income</h2>
        <input v-model="form.income" v-on:keyup="updateIncome" @change="updateIncome" type="number" class="form-control" name="income" id="income" placeholder="Income">
        <h2>Expenses</h2>
        <div class="budget" v-for="budget in budgetKeys">
            <h3>{{budget}}</h3>
            <budget-line v-on:update-expense="calculateExpense($event, budget)"></budget-line>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: This doesn't make the subtraction function automatically fire on keyup.